# How to group headers of PrimeFaces dataTable with dynamic columns

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using slightly modified Dynamic Columns from [PrimeFaces Showcase: Dynamic columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml). Now my task is to add column header grouping as here [PrimeFaces Showcase: Group](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml). I am trying to start incrementaly, but even this small code doesn't work (no header are shown):

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable" var="result" value="#{myBean.searchResults}">  
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.columns}" var="column" >
                <p:column headerText="#{column.header}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:columns value="#{myBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
        <h:outputText value="#{result[column.property]}"/>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

PrimeFaces version 3.4.1

Answer (score -1):

Grouping dynamic columns is at least supported in a  newer PF version. But only all columns under the same group. But there must be additional code. Check the showcase link you point to

(Ps, will remove this answer later on, since I interpreted the question wrong

Comment: But i see it at Group showcase (2nd link): for example at last table years are grupped under Goals group

Comment: You want ALL columns under the same 'group'? Showcase is running 5.3-SNAPSHOT btw, waaaay newer than your version.

Comment: Thanks, now I see why neither of my attempts did worked. My example was planned minimal to check any grouping at all. At the end I'd like to skip first two columns and group others by pairs (like first/second part of the day). May be I can try http://datatables.net/ or some other solution to achieve this?

Comment: Or use c:foreach in a clever way

Comment: Can you suggest good example? I mainly could find wrong code with other user problems. My question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605610/how-to-use-cforeach-with-primefaces-datatable