# How to use c:forEach with p:dataTable and p:columnGroup?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to use a special form of grouping 'dynamic' columns. This is however not supported as stated in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589079/how-to-group-headers-of-primefaces-datatable-with-dynamic-columns). Using `c:forEach` was suggested as a possible solution

Which is correct way to use `c:forEach` for defining table header and colums. 
My code BEFORE:

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable" var="result" value="#{myBean.searchResults}" scrollable="true">  
    <p:columns value="#{myBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{result[column.property]}"/>
   </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

and code AFTER transformation (didn't work - table is not displayed):

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable" var="result" value="#{myBean.searchResults}" scrollable="true">
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <c:forEach items="#{myBean.columns}" var="column">
                <p:column headerText="#{column.header}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <c:forEach items="#{myBean.columns}" var="column" >
        <p:column> 
            <h:outputText value="#{result[column.property]}"/>
        </p:column>
    </c:forEach>
</p:dataTable>
```

PrimeFaces version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The "by the book" way to create dynamic columns would be to use the ["Dynamic Columns" feature](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml) of the data table.

Any way, I did something very similar to what you are trying to do in the past, using c:forEach. The only difference was that I was not using p:columnGroup at the same time.

So, code like

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable" var="result" value="#{myBean.searchResults}" scrollable="true">
    <c:forEach items="#{myBean.columns}" var="column" >
        <p:column headerText="#{column.header}"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{result[column.property]}"/>
        </p:column>
    </c:forEach>
</p:dataTable>
```

should really work. When you do this way, you add p:column objets in the component tree before the p:datatable analyze the tree. So, this does the trick.

Beware that this can lead to problems in edge, ajax cases. So, if you can, just stick to the built-in dynamic columns feature.

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work. I'd like to transform example from a book to make structure changing more flexible

Comment: he can't use the columns since he wants some special grouping...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589079/how-to-group-headers-of-primefaces-datatable-with-dynamic-columns